# Convert .vhd to .img on windows?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, vhd, img

I have a `.vhd` virtual hard disk. I need to convert it to `.img` disk image. How can I do it? I have Windows 7 and VirtualBox at my disposal, can those tools help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can go with VirtualBox by converting your image using the CLI's `--format raw` argument:

```
VBoxManage clonehd disk.vdi disk.img --format raw
```

As long as VirtualBox can read the input disk image, you should be good to go.

Comment: Excuse this newbie user here: where do I insert this argument line?

Comment: Nevermind I found it out. VBoxManage is an .exe, so I just need to enter the VirtualBox folder, and execute that line via Windows's cmd. Although...Can this be done viceversa (img > vhd)?

Comment: Nevermind, it can be done. By executing "VBoxManage clonehd" it'll say the different possible formats.